# Can the cuda version in docker container be different with the host machine?

Tags: cuda

I want to run the code that is written with cuda8.0 and tensorflow-1.2. I want to run the code in another machine,which the cuda is 9.0, So I use the docker to generate a container,that use this command:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel
```

when I run the code in this container, there is the error below:

```
CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

So, Is it wrong? How to solve that?

Comment: It's not wrong and this should work.  If you are using ordinary docker containers and runtime, that is likely the problem.  The way this can work is to use the [nvidia container runtime](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-runtime) with your docker install.  With that, I do what you are trying to do here quite regularly and easily.

Comment: @RobertCrovella，thanks. But actually, it is something wrong in the result. I detected 60 objects in this container, but the real result should be 11. I get the true in my original machine, but get wrong number in this container.I don't know the reason.

Comment: that sounds like a completely different issue now.  I was responding to the question about `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version`

Comment: @RobertCrovella,thanks for the question about `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version`. I solved the problem. At the same time, I know the wrong result does not be caused by CUDA.

Comment: @Lisa.chen Can you please post, how you solved the problem, I am facing the same issue!

Answer (score 12):

For anyone that stumbles upon this, the issue here is the version of the CUDA driver library on the host is too old for the CUDA runtime library inside the container. The CUDA driver forms part of your NVIDIA driver installation on the host.

The CUDA drivers are not forwards compatible so the host needs to be at least be as recent as the version of the CUDA runtime you are trying to use in the container. For the widest range of options you should update the NVIDIA driver and CUDA driver on the host to the latest stable version.